# Displaying time duration and format properly in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I have an [Order Date] and an [Import Date] (both with time; `MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS AM/PM`) displaying when an order was created and when the order actually imported into another system.

I then added a column with a simple formula `[Import Date] - [Order Date] = [Delayed Import Time]`. This is expressed as a duration 0.00:00:00 (D.HH:MM:SS).

Power BI understands all of this in the Power Query Editor just fine. But when I go to Reports to show a visualization it doesn't display the format of the [Delayed Import Time] in the same duration format `0.00:00:00 (D.HH:MM:SS)`.

It instead displays it as a decimal number.

How can I get this to display as the duration format in something like a matrix table? That way I can see an avg displayed as "0.00:05:12"; ie delayed import of all records is averaging 5:12 mins.

[Order Date and Import Date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85a4q.png)

[Delayed Import Time:shown as a duration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BatZs.png)

[Matrix table displaying avg as decimal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iM8X3.png)

Comment: Did you try plotting in a table instead of a matrix?

Answer (score 0):

On your added calculated column, change the date type to Time (under the Modeling tab).

From there you can select different format options like `hh:mm:ss` though I don't think any of them will have the `dd.` part. If you need that, then you'll likely need to write a measure to format exactly how you want, in which case check out the [`FORMAT` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/custom-date-and-time-formats-for-the-format-function).